# my github ssh behavior didn't match the config

Tags: github, ssh

I want to use 443 port to connect to github.
So I add blow code into ~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
    HostName ssh.github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github
    Port 443
```

But It didn't work.

some try:

first, I try `ssh -v git@ssh.github.com`

```
OpenSSH_9.2p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [20.205.243.160] port 22.
```

It show that, connection still use port 22.

and then I try `ssh -v git@ssh.github.com -p 443`

```
OpenSSH_9.2p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [20.205.243.160] port 443.
...
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@ssh.github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

It show that, connection didn't find my publickey.

So finally I try `ssh -v git@ssh.github.com -p 443 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.github`

```
...
Connection to ssh.github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3460, received 2724 bytes, in 0.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4383.9, received 3451.4
debug1: Exit status 1
```

The connection is correct.

Besides, others config in my ~/.ssh/config work.

Answer (score 0):

To use your Host config setting, you need to use your `Host` section name

```
ssh -Tv github.com
```

(no need for git@, since you have a `User git` in your config file `Host github.com` section)

Then you can check it uses the right port and private key.